# Dynamically generated columns in radgrid disappear after postback

Tags: telerik, postback, radgrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

Am using radgrid and creating it in aspx but on certain action i add more GridTemplateColumns to the grid.

```
private void CreateDateColumns(List<DateTime> occurenceList)
{
    if (occurenceList != null && occurenceList.Count > 0)
    {
        int index = 1;
        foreach (DateTime occurence in occurenceList)
        {
            string templateColumnName = occurence.Date.ToShortDateString();
            GridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new GridTemplateColumn();
            templateColumn.ItemTemplate = new MyTemplate(templateColumnName, index);
            grdStudentAttendanceList.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(templateColumn);
            templateColumn.HeaderText = templateColumnName;
            templateColumn.UniqueName = templateColumnName;

            index++;
        }
    }
}

private class MyTemplate : ITemplate
{
    protected RadComboBox rcbAttendance;
    private string colname;
    private int _index;
    public MyTemplate(string cName, int index)
    {
        colname = cName;
        _index = index;
    }
    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        rcbAttendance = new RadComboBox();
        rcbAttendance.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("---Select---", "-1"));
        rcbAttendance.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("Present", "1"));
        rcbAttendance.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("Absent", "2"));
        rcbAttendance.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("Leave", "3"));
        rcbAttendance.ID = "rcbAttendance" + _index;
        container.Controls.Add(rcbAttendance);
    }
}
```

All are fine with creation but when i press save button or any combobox make postback the only dynamically generated columns content disappear and the other columns stay.
What i noticed that columns still in place with headertext but only content are disappeared (in my case content are comboboxes)

After enabling viewstate for grid only header text appear.

What should i do to keep columns contents after postback and get their values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When creating template columns programmatically, the grid must be generated completely in the code-behind using the Page_Init event. Then, you must create the templates dynamically in the code-behind and assign them to the ItemTemplate and EditItemTemplate properties of the column. To create a template dynamically, you must define a custom class that implements the ITemplate interface. Then you can assign an instance of this class to the ItemTemplate or EditTemplateTemplate property of the GridTemplateColumn object.
>   Blockquote
>
> Column templates must be added in the Page_Init event handler, so that the template controls can be added to the ViewState.
>   Blockquote

Source: [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-programmatic-creation.html)

Basicly, you need to create all GridTemplateColumns in the Page_Init. We had the same problem and this approach fixed it.